# Use numba typed list in a function

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm trying to speed up some simple functions with numba.
The first function below works, but gives a deprecation warning, that says reflection of lists is being removed and to use numba.typed.list.

```
from numba import jit
from numba.typed import List as NBList
import numpy as np
from typing import List


@jit(nopython=True)
def water_added_to_pp_refl(water_added: List[int], vessel_volume: int = 1000
                           ) -> np.ndarray:
    """convert list of amounts of water in mg to array of partial pressures for a given volume"""
    wadd_array = np.array(water_added)
    print(wadd_array)
    return np.divide(wadd_array, vessel_volume)

output_reflected = water_added_to_pp_refl([10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200, 250])  # this works, but warning
```

When I convert my list to  a numba.list, it fails to create the array:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def water_added_to_pp_NBList(water_added: List[int], vessel_volume: int = 1000
                             ) -> np.ndarray:
    """convert list of amounts of water in mg to array of partial pressures for a given volume"""
    water_list = NBList()
    [water_list.append(x) for x in water_added]
    wadd_array = np.array(water_list)
    print(wadd_array)
    return np.divide(wadd_array, vessel_volume)

output_NBListed = water_added_to_pp_NBList([10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200, 250]) # fails to create array
```

With error:

> ```
> There are 2 candidate implementations:
>    - Of which 2 did not match due to:
>    Overload in function 'array': File: numba\core\typing\npydecl.py: Line 482.
>      With argument(s): '(ListType[int64])':
>     Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
>       NotImplementedError: ListType[int64] cannot be represented as a Numpy dtype
> ```

I tried setting the dtype of the array to np.int64, but that didnt work.

How do I use the numba.typed.list with numpy arrays? Is it possible?